# xp_cmdshell runs 7z standalone, but cannot find EXE with parms

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, windows-server-2008

When I invoke xp_cmdshell as below, `7z.exe` actually runs, and its output is correct because no parameters are included:

```
declare @Command VARCHAR(1000)
set @Command = '"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a '
exec master..xp_cmdshell @command
select @Command
```

Output:

```
output
NULL
7-Zip 18.05 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2018-04-30
NULL
NULL
NULL
Command Line Error:
Cannot find archive name
NULL
```

Once I add a file, I get a totally different error: `7z.exe` is not found:

```
declare @Command VARCHAR(1000)
set @Command = '"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a ' + '"' + 'C:\TO_ERASE\ToZip.txt' + '"'
exec master..xp_cmdshell @command
select @Command
```

Output:

```
output
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
NULL
```

What can the problem be?

The only difference is that I added the filename as parameter. I would understand if `7z.exe` generated errors, but Windows is not finding the `exe` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting issue. I went around looking at various solutions regarding a space in the filename and came across **[THIS](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic694445-149-1.aspx)**. I'm not sure why your first example works but their solution was to add something prior to the path so that the path isn't the first thing in the command.

```
declare @Command VARCHAR(1000)
set @Command = 'cd.. && "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a ' + '"' + 'C:\TO_ERASE\ToZip.txt' + '"'
exec master..xp_cmdshell @command
select @Command
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use `cd` as the first command then call the program directly, like this example:

```
DECLARE @p_cmd varchar(255)

SET @p_cmd = 'cd "C:\Program Files\edb\mtk\bin" && runMTK.bat -dataOnly -tables table_changes -sourcedbtype sqlserver -targetdbtype postgresql -targetSchema public dbo'
EXEC xp_cmdshell @p_cmd
```